# Is there any way to set the startup page in Thunderbird to be the latest mail instead of some link?  

Tags: startup, thunderbird, email, mail

Is there any way to set the startup page in Thunderbird to be the latest mail instead of some link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a fix!

You need an **add-on** to enable this functionality (which is default in Apple Mail and Outlook...)

It's called **Select Inbox** and you can download it here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/select-inbox/

Once installed, go to add-ons -> select inbox -> options and select first/last.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the menu, choose Edit > Preferences. It's the forst setting on the first page, called something like Thunderbird start page. (I'm not using English so it might be slightly different, but you'll see it).

Comment: I know that I can deactivate the thunderbird website here. But then the area is simply left blank upon open.